# Database Encoding Issue

Tags: php, sql, encoding

I've created a SQL table with `UTF-8` encoding (by using `engine=MyISAM charset=UTF8;"`).
Now, after inserting the following input : `אבג`, the database contains a record with `&#1488;&#1489;&#1490;`.

I'd like to know whether there's another encoding issue I need to take care of in order to get Hebrew text instead of signs and numbers.

Comment: Nothing SQL related will encode text to *HTML entities*. Likely the browser already did that because you didn't declare the encoding to be used for the form properly. See the duplicate and follow all steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the charset on the mysql connection.
Using mysqli it would be this:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```